# Castle include WCF hosting

Tags: wcf, castle

In our WCF solution we have one ConsoleHost (console application not class library) project and one WasHost Project. We use the Consolehost hosting for Dev environment and WAS hosting for production.

Now there are a number of .config files that are included using "include uri=file://services.config"  in the Castle section of ConsoleHost project. I don't want to make a copy of this services.config  file in the WasHost Project.

Is there a way to include files from other projects without making local copies of them?  Or happy to hear other better ways of doing this.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this a couple of ways.

One is to simply add a link to the source file from both projects as described [here](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/01/20/linking-files-in-visual-studio.aspx).

Alternatively you could embed the config into one of the common assemblies (Build Action=Embedded Resource in the file properties) and then use Castle's ability to include embedded resources. E.g.

```
<include uri="assembly://AssemblyName/xxx.config"/>
```

Comment: Thanks dego.  That did work.  Just one comment... the linking does not work for website projects in VS.  So i had to go with the second suggestion.